# RMI Server - module RMIServer does not "exports Server" to module java.rmi

Tags: java, rmi, java-module

Here is the interface

```
package Server;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface RmiSomme extends Remote{
    
    public abstract void getInformation(String nom, String prenom, int age) throws RemoteException;
    
}
```

Here is the inplementation

```
package Server;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class RmiSommeImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements RmiSomme{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected RmiSommeImpl() throws RemoteException {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void getInformation(String nom, String prenom, int age) throws RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
System.out.println(nom + " " + prenom);
    }

}
```

and this is the server class

```
package Server;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException {
        
        
        try {
            RmiSommeImpl rmi = new RmiSommeImpl();
            LocateRegistry.createRegistry(11);
            Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:11/RMI", rmi);
            System.out.println(rmi.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

When I start the server class this error keep showing up :

> Unable to make public abstract void Server.RmiSomme.getInformation(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int) throws java.rmi.RemoteException accessible: module RMIServer does not "exports Server" to module java.rmi

Comment: You have to use the Java 9+ module-system and open/export your module to the java.rmi module. I.e. You have to allow java.rmi to use your class, which it cant by default.

Comment: thanks I just fixed it by adding the export in module.info.java

Comment: Hi @let'splayit, how did you do it?

Comment: @Zabuzard, how can we allow java.rmi to use our class? Any help would be appreciated.. as I too am getting similar error....

Comment: I got it!!! `exports package_name to java.rmi;` is the command.

Answer (score 2):

You must export your *Server* package by adding the following line into ***module-info.java*** file :

```
exports Server to java.rmi;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your package_name  by adding the following line into module-info.java file :

exports package_name to java.rmi;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).